# regex for mysql query?

Tags: mysql, regex, string

say, I have a `varchar(18) field(name:firmware)` in a mysql database table.

The string format is like: `ABC100-DE-3.10-0347`, or it might looks like `ABC100-DE-3.1-347`. Basically, the only thing I can rely on is the `"-" delimiter`, the last part(`0347,347`) is called build number.

The `3.1/3.10` part is called version number. Is it possible to only select the build number and version number out from this field? I suspect this query might turn help to regex, since string functions won't do the job.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a shot:

```
select SUBSTRING_INDEX(theField,'-',-1) as buildNumber,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(theField,'-',-2),'-',1) as versionNumber
from theTable
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure - try something like `[^-]+-[^-]+-([0-9\.]+)-([0-9]+)`, where the first capturing group is your version number and the second is the build number.

To be specific, the first group looks for a sequence of numbers and periods and the second looks for a sequence of numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The RegEx you're looking for it: `^(?:\w[\w\d]*\-)+(\d[\d\.]*)`

Depending on where you use it you may need start and end delimiters: `/^(?:\w[\w\d]*\-)+(\d[\d\.]*)/`

The assumption is that the first time a delimiter (`-`) is followed by a decimal digit, that's your version number.

Not %100 sure about the MySQL, but something like...

```
SELECT * FROM `MyTable` WHERE `MyColumn` REGEXP '^(?:\w[\w\d]*\-)+(\d[\d\.]*)'
```

... might work.